# User-defined variable in an INSERT query for MySQL

Tags: mysql, variables, insert, user-defined

I need to use user-defined variable in an INSERT query for MySQL, see an example bellow:

```
INSERT INTO `posts`(`id`) VALUES(NULL);
SET @last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `comments`(`id`, `post_id`) VALUES(NULL, "@last_insert_id");
```

This example doesn't work and inserted 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no need to store it in a variable.  You can just call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` inside the following `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO `comments`(`id`, `post_id`) VALUES (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

... unless you have multiple inserts to perform using that id.

In that case, the proper syntax for using the variable is to do so without quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `posts`(`id`) VALUES (NULL);
SET @last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
/* Several new entries using the same @last_insert_id */
INSERT INTO `comments`(`id`, `post_id`) VALUES (NULL, @last_insert_id);
INSERT INTO `comments`(`id`, `post_id`) VALUES (NULL, @last_insert_id);
INSERT INTO `comments`(`id`, `post_id`) VALUES (NULL, @last_insert_id);
INSERT INTO `comments`(`id`, `post_id`) VALUES (NULL, @last_insert_id);
INSERT INTO `comments`(`id`, `post_id`) VALUES (NULL, @last_insert_id);
```

Comment: I need to use user-defined variable. Above was a simple example.

Comment: is it consistent enough i mean if some one else or cron is doing some inserts will the SET @last_insert_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); takes the last id from which auto increment of which table ?!

Comment: @shareef LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a value of the last ID inserted from _the current database connection_. Another user or another cron or similar would be operating on from a different database connection with its own last_insert_id values, and so the values would be consistent.